# Remove '/' in column , check for length of the column

Tags: sql-server

I have a column named Kilometershour and it has some values with '/'. I want to remove this in my DB. I have written a query but it doesn't work.

```
case when LEN(TEST.TEST_Kilometers +TEST.hour )=1 THEN '' 
ELSE (TEST.TEST_Kilometers +'/'+TEST.hour) END Kilometershour
```

Comment: Perhaps some some sample data and desired results would be helpful and eliminate assumptions

Comment: Please do not use the phrase "It doesn't work". We have no idea what that means. Does it throw an error? Does it produce results, but not the results you want? Please be very descriptive in why it does not work to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "remove the /"?

If you are attempting to simply remove the / from the field as a whole, you could do a SQL REPLACE that and have the replacement character be a space.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Keep in mind that your above query will return back "bad" data if either of your fields contain a NULL. You may need to use a ISNULL to properly concatenate the 3 values together.